# Laravel 4.1 session variables getting randomly forgotten

Tags: session, laravel-4, session-variables

I'm using a Laravel 4.1 app on Apache, and everything is working fine on my local dev machine, but on my staging machine (which is on a shared host) users are randomly getting logged out and prompted to enter their credentials again.

The relevant settings:

app/config/session.php:

```
<?php
return array(
    'driver' => 'file',
    'lifetime' => 120,
    'expire_on_close' => true,
    'files' => storage_path().'/sessions',
    'connection' => null,
    'table' => 'sessions',
    'lottery' => array(2, 100),
    'cookie' => 'laravel_session',
    'path' => '/',
    'domain' => null,
    'secure' => false,
);
```

- using Laravel's default authentication driver
- php.ini:

  - gc_maxlifetime=1440
  - gc_probability=1
  - gc_divisor=100

This does not seem to be the same as the issue some others have experienced [here](http://forumsarchive.laravel.io/viewtopic.php?id=10839).  The session file is not getting cleared by php.  Just a few of the session variables are getting dropped randomly.

I `tail -F`'d the session file and could see when the variables are getting dropped between one request and the next.  It looks like this (formatted for easier reading) before:

```
a:4:{
    s:5:"flash";a:2:{s:3:"old";a:0:{}s:3:"new";a:0:{}}
    s:6:"_token";s:40:"hvuw9VWWjssSwUL2C5eVSn0qZ2g1cwVF5YCEsLG7";
    s:38:"login_82e5d2c56bdd0811318f0cf078b78bfc";i:2;
    s:9:"_sf2_meta";a:3:{s:1:"u";i:1399318721;s:1:"c";i:1399318011;s:1:"l";s:1:"0";}}
```

and after:

```
a:3:{
    s:6:"_token";s:40:"7o3b6NhiuDKXq4ftvngUefqe6cWybX1tzPEcDaxk";
    s:9:"_sf2_meta";a:3:{s:1:"u";i:1399318721;s:1:"c";i:1399318721;s:1:"l";s:1:"0";}
    s:5:"flash";a:2:{s:3:"old";a:0:{}s:3:"new";a:0:{}}}
```

The login_ session is gone, which results in Laravel's Session class assuming the user is not authenticated.  I am not sure why this session variable is getting dropped, though.  None of Session::forget, ::clear(), ::remove() or ::invalidate() are being called on the login session variable as far as I can tell.

I also noticed that the _token variable is constant between requests until the moment when the issue arises at which point it changes, as you can see above.

Any idea what's going on here?

Comment: Can you please post your full session config? Also - can you try an alternative session drive? maybe database temporarily to see if the problem persits?

Comment: Ok, I've posted my session.php above

Comment: Although not entirely a problem - change your cookie name to 'something' - dont use underscores - it might cause an issue. Also - try and turn off expire_on_close and see if that helps. http://stackoverflow.com/q/15016204/1317935

Comment: I think your sessions are being destroyed and re-generated. That is why you have a new token when you lose the _login data.

Comment: I'm not convinced that the sessions are being destroyed because the session files remain intact with the same filename/id through the whole process.  Wouldn't there be a new session file if it was being destroyed?

Comment: Changing to the database driver seems to make things work.

Answer (score 0):

Switching to the database session manager seems to have solved the problem.  I suspect that there was some way on my host server configuration that php was wiping out the session files.